# Putty not working on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: putty

Putty always just worked for me, and I've never had a moment's bother with it until now. Since installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS it hasn't worked.  I have purged it from the system and reinstalled, but the result is the same. When I try to SSH to one of the sites on which it worked perfectly previously, now it simply disappears as soon as I press "open".

Can anyone help me get my old pal Putty back again?

Terence.

Comment: I just installed `putty` on my 22.04 to see if I could duplicate your issue, but I can't.  Is it only one site that you are not able to connect to but you are able to connect to others?  Have you tried to connect to the site with another system to make sure that the other site isn't the issue?  Is there anything special you would have had to do previous to connect to the site like using a certificate, Proxy, cipher?  Please add details to your question and not in comments here as they can be deleted.

Comment: Why would you need putty for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too. When running from terminal it shows **PuTTY: unable to load font "server:fixed"**
In **Window > Fonts**, click change and select one of them. Looks OK so far after that.

Answer (score 0):

22.04.1-Ubuntu.

On terminal type:

sudo echo 'export GDK_BACKEND=x11' > /etc/profile.d/PuTTy.sh

Close session, log in again and try.